# XML's xsi:nil not deserializing to null

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, xml-deserialization

I got a C# project, which I decompiled from existing dlls. It uses Microsoft.Web.Services2 and System.Web.Services. My client didn't have the sources, so you know ;D

There's a generated method from a WSDL contract:

```
[SoapDocumentMethod("", ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare, Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
[return: XmlElement("getOutputMessageResponse", Namespace = "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/human-task/services/6.0")]
public XmlElement getOutputMessage([XmlElement("getOutputMessage", Namespace = "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/human-task/services/6.0")] getOutputMessage getOutputMessage1)
{
  return (XmlElement) this.Invoke("getOutputMessage", new object[1]
  {
    (object) getOutputMessage1
  })[0];
}
```

In the code, I got this:

```
XmlElement output = ... // getOutputMessage() invocation

if(output != null){
    // do something...
}else{
    // do something else
}
```

And here's the problem. The output is NEVER NULL. It either becomes:

```
<wn:procesResponse xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wn="http://website" />
```

or a correctly filled `XML` response.

It should get `null`ed because of the `xsi:nil`, and the best part is that - it was working before decompilation, so I have some settings missing or something like that.

Do you have any ideas, what may be the problem here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The first line of the Xml is valid since it contains its own namespace 'wn'.  You do not get any children because they are using the default namespace not 'wn'.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I don't get any children. And that's why I should have get a NULL XmlElement (because of xsi:nil=true). But I don't get a null, and I don't know why.

Comment: Why would you have a null xml when you have an ident line and a root element?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve that, but I know it's possible - because this is how the code is written. It checks for null: `if(xmlOutput != null)`. So it's possible for the webservice to return null, if there's xsi:nil. But in my case, it doesn't work. It returns a normal response with xsi:nil inside.

Comment: I don't think so.  The response is xml so returning a null would not make sense.  You would have to return a null response which means you do not send a response (then you would get a timeout). You need to send a response but the body of the response would be null which is what you are getting.